# How to display only the table of contents on main page in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

The subsections are displayed below the TOC.
I want the Table of contents to be displayed on the main page without the subsections.
The items in the TOC should open a new Wiki page.
[Headers displayed below TOC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ErbH.png)

I don't want the orange part to be displayed.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't currently possible in MediaWiki. It would be easiest to just add links to your content on the main page, and then have the content itself on other pages.

If you want, you can style the links so that they look like a table of contents. Try adding the following wikitext to your main page:

```
<div role="navigation" class="toc plainlinks">
'''Contents'''

* [[Foo]]
* [[Bar]]
* [[Baz]]
</div>
```